# TypeError: collection.some is not a function multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

When trying to display dynamic texts on selection of items, getting error as below:

[image]

On updation or if no items selected, getting error as: [image]

**Following is my code:**

```
             vm.multiSelectSettings = {
                enableSearch: true,
                scrollable: true,
                dynamicTitle: true,
                displayProp: 'displayName',
                idProp: 'displayName',
                smartButtonMaxItems: 3,
                smartButtonTextConverter: function(itemText, originalItem) {
                    return itemText;
                }
            };

             vm.defaultMultiSelectText = {buttonDefaultText: '- Please Select -'};

             <div checkboxes="true"
             name="{{entityDefinition.name}}"
             class="add-entity-multiselect"
             ng-dropdown-multiselect=""
             options="entityDefinition.formElemItems"
             extra-settings="vm.multiSelectSettings"
             selected-model="vm.entity.attributes[entityDefinition.name]"
             translation-texts="vm.defaultMultiSelectText"></div>
```

Strange is still the records are created and updated. What's going wrong here? What is missing? Has anybody faced similar issue? Please assist

Comment: please provide your code details

Comment: @JijoCleetus - I have already shared code above, what more details you need? Basically this multiselect is in ng-repeat which is loading from entitydefinitions. And no need to bother selected-model as its working fine.

Comment: is that all the code you have not use length there so where is it being used .. another thing could you comment out the setting part of the input and see if it works

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome: Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been resolved [here](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/314).

There were multiple issues with it but in short the real issue was:

- "selected-model" was undefined instead of an array
- lodash was not included whilst the version that was being used was an old version that was still dependent on lodash

Comment: I have re-opened the issue @pkempenaers. Thats not the cause. Please have a luk here: https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/315

Comment: It may not be the exact answer in my cause, but still i appreciate for your quickest response in resolving one bug with the latest release